# PeekMessage inside thread

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2012, c++11

I'm a bit confused. What I'm trying to do - is to create *a window messages loop inside a different thread*. My code looks like this:

```
//...
#include <thread>
//...

void MyClass::runMainLoop() {
    new thread(mainLoop, this); //I know this will cause a memory leak - just for testing
}

void MyClass::mainLoop(MyClass* _this) { // <- static method
    cout << "start thread" << endl; //loop function started
    MSG msg;
    while (true) {
        while (PeekMessage(&msg, _this->_hWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            cout << msg.message << " "; //we've got a message! (don't get here inside a thread)
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) {
                cout << "exiting" << endl; //closing window
                break;
            }
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        Sleep(2);
    }
}
```

The message "start thread" appears, but I don't see that any messages where handled. On the other hand, when I call to mainLoop() method without creating a thread, everything seems to work fine:

```
void MyClass::runMainLoop() {
    mainLoop(this);
}
```

I tryed to dig into MSDN, but didn't find anything on my problem. It seems, that I have some gaps in my knowledge, which can't be filled in a reasonable time.

My thought was that the thread somehow "don't know" about a window I've created inside my main program thread.

So, the question is - what am I doing wrong? Why the message loop isn't working in thread?

**EDIT:**

The code which creates the window. It runs in the program's main thread.

```
WNDCLASSEX            wcx;
PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
RECT                  rect;
HGLRC                 hRCTemp;
DWORD                 style, exStyle;
int                   x, y, format;

_hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL);

//Register window class
memset(&wcx, 0, sizeof(wcx));
wcx.cbSize        = sizeof(wcx);
wcx.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
wcx.lpfnWndProc   = (WNDPROC)windowProc;
wcx.hInstance     = _hInstance;
wcx.lpszClassName = L"windowClassName";
wcx.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wcx.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);

RegisterClassEx(&wcx)

//Window styles
style   = WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX;
exStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW;

//place window at the cetner of the screen
x = (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - width)  / 2;
y = (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - height) / 2;

rect.left   = x;
rect.right  = x + width;
rect.top    = y;
rect.bottom = y + height;

//Adjust  window size to styles
AdjustWindowRectEx(&rect, style, FALSE, exStyle);

//Create a window
_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(exStyle, wcx.lpszClassName, L"Window caption", style, rect.left, rect.top,
    rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, NULL, NULL, _hInstance, NULL);
```

**EDIT 2:**

Thanks to all those who commented my question, I understand now where the problem is: *the thread that created the window receives the messages for it*.

So, I'll rephrase the question: **can I redirect window messages to another thread**? I tried [AttachThreadInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but didn't succeed.

Comment: Since you didn't post any code that showed that you also created a window on that thread, it is entirely expected that you don't get any message at all.

Comment: In other words, the thread that creates a window is the one that receives messages for that window.

Comment: @HansPassant I've posted the code which creates the window.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Could you please explain what you mean? Does it mean, that there is **absolutely** no way to run a messages loop in another thread?

Comment: Jonathan said it quite clearly: The thread that created the window receives the messages for it. Your thread does not create a window anywhere in the code you posted. The code you posted, as you clearly state, runs in the program's main thread. The program's main thread is not the same as the thread you create with `new thread()`.

Comment: @MartinJames Why should I want to replace PeekMessage() with GetMessage()? As far as I understand, GetMessage is blocking, while PeekMessage - is not. After a loop with DispatchMessage I have some OpenGL rendering code - so it is critical that it will be executed without a delay.

Comment: This question is answered. Please ask a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An HWND is tied to the thread context that it is created in.  Only the thread context that creates an HWND can receive messages for that HWND.  When you call `mainLoop()` directly in `runMainLoop()`, `mainLoop()` is running in the same thread context that created the HWND, which is why it works.  Once you move `mainLoop()` to a different thread, it can no longer receive messages for the HWND.

An HWND's message pump **must** be in the same thread that created the HWND.  There is no getting around that limitation.  So if you want to service the HWND in a different thread then you have to create the HWND in that thread.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do would be a producer/consumer model.

When you create your window, add a handler that will add to a queue:

```
// Global scope...
std::queue<MSG*> g_messages;
std::mutex g_mutex;
std::condition_variable g_cond;
```

Then your main loop would look like (for the thread that created the window):

```
void MyClass::mainLoop(MyClass* _this) { // <- static method
    while (true) {
        MSG *msg = new MSG;
        while (PeekMessage(msg, _this->_hWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(g_mutex);
            g_messages.push(msg);
            g_cond.notify_all();
        }

        DispatchMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

And create your threads like this:

```
std::thread t([]() {
    MSG *msg;
    while (true) {
        // Wait for a message
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(g_mutex);
            while (g_messages.empty()) g_cond.wait(lock);
            msg = g_messages.front();
            g_messages.pop();
        }

        // Got a message, process it
        if (msg->message == WM_QUIT) {
            cout << "exiting" << endl; //closing window
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually, I've come to use something like this. But I though to go further and completely eliminate this while loop from the main program thread.

Answer (score 0):

**response to your EDIT 2**

You can redirect the messages of the window to another thread by creating the window in the thread. The thread must not only handle the messages, but also the creation via an event-driven model and MsgWaitForMultipleObjects. Or via a private message you send from main thread to the created thread via PostThreadMessage.

The latter model:

from main thread:

- create the thread
- call PostThreadMessage(tid, MYPRIVATEMESSAGE, wparam, lparam)

in the thread created:

```
loop GetMessage() 
{

  if (message == MYPRIVATEMESSAGE)
  {
    create the window, use wParam/lParam to pass optional parameters
  }
  else
  {  
    translate message
    dispatch message
  }
}
```